# Sub replication of contingent claims

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to prove subreplication cost is the infimum of risk neutral expectation of the contingent claim. I wonder if the following equality holds, which is the key to the proof.
$$
\lim_n \inf_{Q\in \mathcal M}\mathbb E^Q[Z\wedge n] = \inf_{Q\in \mathcal M}\mathbb E^Q[Z]
$$
where $Z\in L^1$ is a non-negative contingent claim and $\mathcal M$ is the class of equivalent local martingale measures. I don't know whether this is true or a counterexample can be constructed. Any idea in this regard is much appreciated.